# Flex - setting data provider and row count on a datagrid causes rows to be hovered over from outside the grid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mouseover, dataprovider, rowcount

I have a UIComponent that has a subclass of datagrid at the top and a button "removeValues" at the bottom.

When the removeValues button is clicked, I call `resetDataProvider`in the datagrid, which sets the dataprovider to about half the number of values that were previously in the data provider and resizes the datagrid to x number of rows when value is less than/equal to 6.

I've noticed a weird issue when I hover over the bottom of the component after it's been resized. One of the rows remaining in the grid is highlighted (as if I've hovered over it) when I hover over the bottom of the UIComponent (which looks like empty space).

I listen for a mouseOver event on the datagrid and sure enough, it thinks it's hovering over one of my item renderers for a datagrid row.

I've tried invalidateList(), validateNow(), invalidateDisplayList(), but nothing seems to update it properly. Has anyone got any ideas on what I could try?

```
public function resetDataProvider(value:XMLList):void
{               
        dataProvider = value;

        if(value.length() <= DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT)
        {
            this.rowCount = value.length();
            height = measureHeightOfItems(-1, rowCount+1) + viewMetrics.top + viewMetrics.bottom;
        }

        invalidateList();
        validateNow()
}
```

[image: Putting the Mouse Over the white area beside the Remove button highlights the second item in the list]

Edit:

Just an update on this: the issue goes away when I scroll down the grid (more than 6 rows) and scroll back up. Is there a way to mimic the update it's doing programmatically?

Comment: If you mean that the list flows over the actual grid, I have found that setting maxWidth for the grid has solved the problem for me before. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Hi, I've added a screencap. When I mouse over the whitespace beside the remove button (After I've adjusted the rowcount to fit the data), the second row becomes highlighted and if I click in the whitespace, it selects the row.